# How to clear Symantec Endpoint Protection logs

Tags: windows-7, logging, symantec

In Symantec Endpoint Protection, I want all the logs to be cleared. E.g., in Antivirus and Antispyware Protection Logs, and Risk Log tab, when I select an item and click either Clean or Delete, I got an error message and nothing got cleared. Any workaround?

EDIT:
I'm using managed Endpoint Protection, version 11.0.62, OS is Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. A little more info will help us help you. What operating system are you using? Are you on a managed network (network administrator other than you) or a personal computer? What version of End Point? All of these things matter when it comes to being able to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you @CharlieRB, I've updated the question to include such information.

Comment: Forgot to ask if you can post the error message or a screen shot?

Comment: If managed client, has the admin set a retention period for logs?

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Is this PC part of a domain, with SEP managed by the domain server?

Comment: @CharlieRB, there's no error message, just nothing happens when I click the Clear or Delete button in the log window. To

Comment: How can this be done in Mac ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make Symantec Endpoint auto delete the logs by making the logs seem older than 6 months. For this:

1. Move ahead your system date by 6 months.
2. Save and restart the system.
3. Check... all your logs would have already been removed.
4. Reset your system date to today's date.